# Google Console crash report on Production App

Tags: codenameone

I see following error message in android play store crash errors. I'm not able to see the error in simulator. How would I debug this message. Please advise.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: at com.codename1.impl.android.InPlaceEditView.a(InPlaceEditView.java:811)
at com.codename1.impl.android.InPlaceEditView.a(InPlaceEditView.java:89)
at com.codename1.impl.android.InPlaceEditView$10.run(InPlaceEditView.java:1567)
```

Comment: You need to file these issues in the issue tracker. This is an exception from Codename One's Android implementation so we need that information there: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/